# Retrieve from dynamically named tables

Tags: etl, talend, analysis

I'm using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration.

I have tables that are generated every day and table names are suffixed by date like so

- dailystats20220127
- dailystats20220126
- dailystats20220125
- dailystats20220124

I have two-part question.
I want to look at the table which has yesterday's date in it so sysdate - 1 and I want to fetch data from yesterday

```sql
select 'dailystats' ||to_char(sysdate - 1,'YYYYMMDD') TableName  
from  dual;
```

1. How do I retrieve schema for a dynamic name?
2. How do I pull data from that table.

[image]

I've worked with static table names and its a straightforward process.

Comment: Is the schema of the daily tables always the same ? Are you using open studio or the enterprise version ?

Comment: I am using Open Studio. Yes, the schema will be the same. 
DB, Schema, Column names, data types will remain constant. The table name will change depending on the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the schema is always the same, you just define it once in your input component.
2. In your input component set the sql as :

> "select [fields] from dailystats"+ TalendDate.formatDate("yyyyMMdd", TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.getCurrentDate(), -1, "dd"))

Comment: I stand corrected. The schema will change, so new day, a new table will be created.
Under Schema -> Repository Content how do I select the last table which was generated.

Comment: if you are working with open studio, you can't change the schema dynamically. There is a dynamic schema feature available but only in paid version.

Comment: found a way around to make the schema same and your answer worked. Just wanted to circle back and thank you :)